# Repeated disk writes

Tags: java, c++, file-io, disk

I need to write a list of words to a file and then save the file on a disk. Is one of the following two ways better than the other? The second one obviously uses more main memory but is there a difference in speed?

(this is just pseudocode)

```
for i = 0 to i = n:
    word = generateWord();
    FileWriter.println(word);
end loop
```

versus

```
String [] listOfWords = new List
for i = 0 to i = n:
    word = generateWord();
    listOfWords.add(word)
end loop
for i = 0 to n:
    FileWriter.println(listOfWords[i]);
end loop
```

Comment: There is no big difference. It depends on if you are reusing the list of words.

Answer (score 2):

These two methods you show are exactly the same in terms of disk usage efficiency.

When thinking about speed of disk writes, you must always take into account what kind of writer object you are using. There are many types of writer objects and each of them may behave differently when it comes to actual disk writes.

If the object you are using is one of those that write the exact data you tell it to, then your way of writing is very inefficient. You should consider switching to another writer (BufferedWriter for example) or building a longer string before writing it.

In general, you should try to write data in chunks that fit the disk's chunk size.

Answer (score 1):

Between your code and the disk, you have a stack something like: Java library code, a virtual machine runtime, the C runtime library, the operating system file cache/virtual memory subsystem, the operating system I/O scheduler, a device driver and the physical disk firmware.

Just do the simplest thing possible unless profiling shows a problem. Several of those layers will already be tuned to handle buffering, batching and scheduling sequential writes since they're such a common use case.

Answer (score 0):

From `FileWriter`s standpoint you are doing the exacty same thing in both examples, so clearly there cannot be any difference regarding file I/O. And, as you say, the first one's space complexity is O(1), as opposed to second one's O(N).